# Adding support for REGEXP() in SQLite through Haskell HDBC?

Tags: sql, regex, haskell, sqlite

I've unfortunately just realized that having committed to HDBC as a database access framework for connecting to my SQLite3 database, the ability to add a function to handle `REGEXP()` in SQLite SQL seems to exists only in `Database.SQLite`.

Regular expression is something I need in the application at SQL level, but before I start converting everything to `Database.SQLite` I just thought I'd ask whether there are other options...?

Comment: Do you mean you want to define a custom regexp function from HDBC? As though providing a "C" function? In which case almost certainly not - a database abstraction layer is never going to offer something as specific as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

I see that HDBC may not be able to provide this ability, but I found this extension for SQLite:

https://github.com/eatnumber1/sqlite-regexp

which will do just that via an SQL LOAD statement. Of course, this adds an external dependency, but it fixas the problem (without having to rewrite lots and lots of code).

EDIT:

Actually, it seems that I cannot use `load_extension(X)` inside of HDBC, which means that I cannot loda the extension. So this is still an open issue.